# Manipulation of inferior and superior limits of a summation

Tags: summation, geometric-series

Can you tell me if it's ok to manipulate the limit of a summation in this way please?

$$ \sum \limits _{l = k_o}^{+ \infty} q^{l - k_0} = \sum \limits _{l - k_0 = 0}^{+ \infty} q^{l - k_0} $$

Are there rules about the possible operations I can perform on the superior and inferior limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you are doing, but this is unconventional to have an equation in the lower index of the summation. Less confusing variant involves the change of variable:
$$
\sum \limits _{l = k_0}^{+ \infty} q^{l - k_0} \stackrel{}{=} \sum \limits _{n = 0}^{+ \infty} q^{n}
$$

If you are afraid the reader cannot follow, you can add *substituting summation index $n=l-k_0$* somewhere in the text